# Repeating my text on my textView Objective C

Tags: objective-c, xcode

How do I make the following script repeat the text input into it?

```
self.textView.text = self.userTextInput
```

The above script was written as a text input from a `ViewController` but I want it to loop 10 times in its text viewer, how do I write that?

thanks.

Comment: You can add this using loop:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use following code to get your desired result.

```
NSMutableString *teststring = [NSMutableString string];
for(int i = 0; i<10;i++)
{
[teststring appendString:self.userTextInput];
}
self.textView.text = teststring;
```